# Looping my data file in postman runner, can I schedule individual request from runner itself?

Tags: postman, monitor, postman-collection-runner, postman-pre-request-script

I am running a collection runner in a loop with data file. I have to make a hit to three apis consecutively but When the third api runs, I need to schedule another api with same request after 15 mins. How can I do this with postman?

P.S= I want to run my api asynchronously in postman without blocking the other apis which are calling in a loop.

Comment: What did you already try? Please share your requests. What concrete issues are you facing? Thanks for considering [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

So, I wasn't able to call my api asynchronously in postman.

Therefore I made a node app with the module `**newman**`. With the help of newman I can call two collections consecutively (or after 10 minutes depending on the usecase)